# Javascript and CSS file conflicting with one another

Tags: javascript, css, conflict

I have a function that calculates total price and displays it under div tags. The function used to work and display the total on my old webpage. On my new webpage, I've added a tab template that stores the body, or content, under a huge div tag named content. Now, the Javascript function isn't working (**Javascript.js**). When I remove the link to the css for the tabs, it works again. Here is the css file that's conflicting (**style3.css**):

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

.tabs input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs input#tab-2{
    left: 120px;
}
.tabs input#tab-3{
    left: 240px;
}
.tabs input#tab-4{
    left: 360px;
}

.tabs label {
    background: #5ba4a4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%, #4e8c8a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5ba4a4), color-stop(100%,#4e8c8a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #5ba4a4 0%,#4e8c8a 100%);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    color: #385c5b;
    top: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.tabs label:after {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    display: block;
}

.tabs input:hover + label {
    background: #5ba4a4;
    top: -8px;
    -webkit-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    transition: top linear 0.2s;
}
.tabs input:hover + label:after{
    background: #5ba4a4;
}
.tabs input:hover + label ~ .clear-shadow {
    top: -8px;
    -webkit-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    transition: top linear 0.2s;
}

.tabs input:checked:hover + label {
    top: 0;
}
.tabs input:checked:hover + label:after{
    background: #fff;
}
.tabs input:checked:hover + label ~ .clear-shadow {
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-1:hover + label.tab-label-1 ~ .clear-shadow{
    z-index: 3;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-2:hover + label.tab-label-2 ~ .clear-shadow {
    z-index: 2;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-3:hover + label.tab-label-3 ~ .clear-shadow {
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-4:hover + label.tab-label-4 ~ .clear-shadow {
    z-index: 0;
}
.tabs label:first-of-type {
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.tab-label-2 {
    z-index: 3;
}

.tab-label-3 {
    z-index: 2;
}

.tab-label-4 {
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs input:checked + label {
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 6;
    -webkit-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: top linear 0.2s;
    transition: top linear 0.2s;
}

.clear-shadow {
    background: #5ba4a4;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    clear: both;
    z-index: -2;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.content {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1250px;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}

.content div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: all linear 0.1s;
    transition: all linear 0.1s;
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .content .content-3,
.tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .content .content-4 {
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.2s;
    transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.2s;
}

.content div h2,
.content div h3{
    color: #398080;
}
.content div p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    border-left: 8px solid rgba(63,148,148, 0.1);
}
.indent {
    text-indent: 7px;
}

.totalPrice {
    display: block;
}
```

I won't post the full javascript file (unless any of you think it'll help), but I'll post the content in between the  tags:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"/>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle for the same , it will be easy to fix your issue

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/QcXa5/

Comment: can u provide the absolute path of these resources,style3.css,stylesheet.jss and javascript,js. without this fiddle wont work.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe this is your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"/>
</script>
```

This could be treated as 2 script tags...  because this `/>` on some elements means the end of a tag

> Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: That *could* cause a problem, but at the worst it would be that the second (closing) script tag wouldn't do anything. In HTML5, self-closing tags are parsed but it doesn't mean anything. (All depends on doctype I guess.)

Comment: still doesn't work :/, I guess Pointy's right

Comment: Im looking at your fiddle and can't identify the problem? what's should i be looking at?

Comment: basically when you get rid of my style3.css tag link, inside the <head></head> tags, the javascript works. but when you include the style3.css, it doesn't work. The javascript shows a price below "Total Price: "